# Sketching the garphs of the initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $y'= 2x \cos^2y$

How can i sketch the graphs of the initial value problems $y(0)=0$ and $y(0)= \pi/2$

i use the sepation of variables technique and I find it
$y=\arctan(x^2-c)$

Is it true ?

Comment: If $y(0)= \pi/2$ then the unique solution is $y\equiv \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have:

$$\text{y}\space'\left(x\right)=2x\cdot\cos\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\int\frac{\text{y}\space'\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)}\space\text{d}x=\int2x\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, use:

- $$\int\frac{\text{y}\space'\left(x\right)}{\cos\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)}\space\text{d}x=\tan\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)+\text{C}_1\tag2$$
- $$\int2x\space\text{d}x=x^2+\text{C}_2\tag3$$

So:

$$\tan\left(\text{y}\left(x\right)\right)=x^2+\text{C}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\pi\cdot\text{n}+\arctan\left(x^2+\text{C}\right)\tag4$$

Where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $1+x^2+\text{C}\ne0$